# Can UUIDs which are generated with load balanced servers duplicate?

Tags: laravel, load-balancing, uuid

If two application servers generate Uuids at the same time, is there a chance of duplication?

I am trying to use Uuids as primary.

Should I throw an exception if there is a duplicate.

Or how can I prevent this.

Comment: This chance though very samall, is never ZERO.

Comment: @DariushEivazi In my case, the chance might be greater because of many concurrent requests.

Comment: Actually it is yet too small to happen in lifetime of a good application. Your idea to throw an exception is good but how are you going to manage race condition: two server make identical UUID s while a few milliseconds before, last time they checked, there was not such an UUID in database and it is valid to insert.

Comment: Please check this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier   Read the Collision

Comment: @DariushEivazi It can be achieved by specifying unique to the column and put insert query inside Laravel DB transaction since it will rollback when a SQL exception was thrown.

Comment: Check this link who want to know more about Uuid generation, collisions and how to prevent them. [https://www.sohamkamani.com/uuid-versions-explained/](https://www.sohamkamani.com/uuid-versions-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

As you see in this picture, each UUID has some parameters that help to generate a Unique string, and time and hardware are two parameters that involve in generating it, so if you generate it at the same time, most probably there are different.

[image]